# LDAP Integration with the firewall

Tags: active-directory, firewall, ldap

I am trying to integrate Sonicwall NSA2400 with AD so users can VPN with their domain credentials and able to change password if it expires.

Do i need to install ADLS role and configure LDAP, or LDAP is already built in within the ADDS role?

I have tried to do it without ADLS role and was able to connect using unencrypted connection over port 389 but the VPN client doesn't allow to change password since its unencrypted and it will be sent in clear text so i need to enable TLS over port 636.

When I ebable TLS on the sonicwall, i am not able to connect to LDAP server, how can i configure this to work over TLS?

Comment: Ok, i guess i figured it out. I dont need ADLS role, all i need is CA server to issue certificate and bind it to my domain controller that should open up port 636.